# Converting [x,y] to separate lists of [x] [y]

Tags: python

I am trying to convert [x,y] into two lists of [x] and [y]

Tried the following code:

```
a = [[[0.322, 0.219], [0.334, 0.159], [0.321, 0.139], [0.37, 0.068], 
[0.435, 0.222],[0.146, 0.152], [0.156, 0.027], [0.156, 0.19], [0.269, 
0.124], [0.239, 0.082], [0.22, 0.201]]]

from operator import itemgetter 
a1,b = map(itemgetter(0),a), map(itemgetter(1),a)
print(a1,b)
a1,b = map(list,a)
```

Its giving following error:  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
a =[[0.322, 0.219], [0.334, 0.159], [0.321, 0.139], [0.37, 0.068], 
[0.435, 0.222],[0.146, 0.152], [0.156, 0.027], [0.156, 0.19], [0.269, 
0.124], [0.239, 0.082], [0.22, 0.201]]

b,c = map(list, zip(*a)))
```

or

```
b,c = list(zip(*a))
```

This should probably work as well:

```
b,c = zip(*a)
```

Answer (score 2):

you had an extra set of brackets which I removed, you can use numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[0.322, 0.219], [0.334, 0.159], [0.321, 0.139], [0.37, 0.068], 
[0.435, 0.222],[0.146, 0.152], [0.156, 0.027], [0.156, 0.19], [0.269, 
0.124], [0.239, 0.082], [0.22, 0.201]]

a = np.array(a)

print a

a = np.rot90(a)

print a[0]
print a[1]

>>>
[[ 0.322  0.219]
 [ 0.334  0.159]
 [ 0.321  0.139]
 [ 0.37   0.068]
 [ 0.435  0.222]
 [ 0.146  0.152]
 [ 0.156  0.027]
 [ 0.156  0.19 ]
 [ 0.269  0.124]
 [ 0.239  0.082]
 [ 0.22   0.201]]
[ 0.219  0.159  0.139  0.068  0.222  0.152  0.027  0.19   0.124  0.082
  0.201]
[ 0.322  0.334  0.321  0.37   0.435  0.146  0.156  0.156  0.269  0.239
  0.22 ]
```

docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html

then to get back to list format:

```
x_list = a[0].tolist()
y_list = a[1].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [item[0] for item in a[0]]
y = [item[1] for item in a[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also split this up using a comprehension.

```
a = [[[0.322, 0.219], [0.334, 0.159], [0.321, 0.139], [0.37, 0.068], 
[0.435, 0.222],[0.146, 0.152], [0.156, 0.027], [0.156, 0.19], [0.269, 
0.124], [0.239, 0.082], [0.22, 0.201]]]

a1,b = [ i[0] for i in a[0]],[ i[1] for i in a[0]]

print(a1,b)
```

the above kept all the brackets from your original question. If you did have an extra set unintentionally then you could use this to build the lists

```
a1,b = [ i[0] for i in a],[ i[1] for i in a]
```